# Categorizing by attribute using custom QGIS plugin via python programming?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, style

I'd like to ask on how can I categorize by attribute using my shapefile via python / custom plugin.

I have a Municipality and field name of "Land_Classification" with values "Residential, Commercial and Industrial". I would like to create a plugin that if i click it the layer will automatically categorize the shapefile by Land Classification and will be have colors by Residential, Commercial and Industrial.

Comment: Perhaps these posts can help get you started: [Symbology of vector layers in QGIS Python Plugins](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/); and [How to apply categorized symbols to polygon layer with PyQgis?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/how-to-apply-categorized-symbols-to-polygon-layer-with-pyqgis); and [Apply symbol to each feature (Categorized symbol)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/apply-symbol-to-each-feature-categorized-symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid creating a function in your plugin which allows the user to click a layer and apply a certain style (unless you add some sort of checkbox to enable/disable this function).

What I would do is:

1. Create a **combo box** and populate this with the names of the loaded layers
2. Create a **function** which defines the parameters of the categorised style
3. Create a **push button** which applies the above function to the selected layer in the combo box

---

So you could use something like the following in your *main.py* file. Add the imports at the top of the script:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsSymbolV2, QgsRendererCategoryV2, QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
```

Then in the main `run()` function, you can use:

```
def run(self):
    # Define a list for layer names
    layer_list = []
    # Get all layer names loaded in QGIS and store them in the list   
    for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        layerName = layer.name()
        layer_list.append(layerName)
    # Clear layer combo box to make sure if plugin is loaded again, the list is not duplicated
    self.dlg.comboBox_layer.clear()
    # Add layers from list to combobox
    self.dlg.comboBox_layer.addItems(layer_list)

    def apply_style():
        # Get currently selected layer in combo box
        current_layer = self.dlg.comboBox_layer.currentText()
        layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(str(current_layer))[0]

        # Define style parameters: value, colour, legend
        land_class = {
        'Residential': ('#f00', 'Residential'),
        'Commercial': ('#0f0', 'Commercial'),
        'Industrial': ('#fff', 'Industrial'),
        }

        # Define a list for categories
        categories = []
        # Define symbology depending on layer type, set the relevant style parameters
        for classes, (color, label) in land_class.items():
            symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
            symbol.setColor(QColor(color))
            category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(classes, symbol, label)
            categories.append(category)

        # Column/field name to be used to read values from
        column = 'Land_Class'
        # Apply the style rendering
        renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(column, categories)
        layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
        # Refresh the layer
        layer.triggerRepaint()

    # Set up push button to connect to above function
    run_button = self.dlg.style_button
    run_button.clicked.connect(apply_style)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks sir Joseph. Sorry for my late reply I was out of town for projects. I will try what you suggested and will give you feedback.

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - Most welcome! I implemented something very similar recently so thought to post it as it might be helpful =)

Comment: In step 2 im getting a little confused.. how can I create a function thats not in a plugin?

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - Apologies, probably not very clear. The function is in the code (`def apply_style():` which you add to the plugin.

Comment: yes I added it already. :) but apparently when i click style_button nothing happens.. I think im missing something..

Comment: Did you reload the plugin or restart QGIS?

Comment: Yes sir. everytime I make changes I reload the plugin and restart qgis.

Comment: Perhaps an indentation issue? The code for the style_button should be outside the `def apply_style():` function but inside the `run(self):` function. A good way to test your plugin is to open the **Python Console** and this will mention if any errors occur. Also, you can add `print` statements after certain lines to see if they are being read.

Comment: Hi sir Joseph. I will try it by tomorrow. because im currently working on time keeping project. :) I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Hi sir Josep, I created a comboBox and named it comboBox_layer also I created a push button and named it style_button. I used the above code in the land_class parameters 'Residential' : ('#f00' , 'Residential') which part of Residential is for database to read? because in land_class field my residential is ALL CAPS.

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - The first part is for values so in your case it would be: `'RESIDENTIAL': ('#f00', 'Residential')`. The syntax is basically `value: ('colour', 'legend')`.

Comment: ok.. trying it now sir @Joseph. :)

Comment: Hi sir Joseph, I tried it again but sad to say when I click on style_button and press ok from dialog box nothing happens.. 

let me confirm step 1. I create a comboBox and name it comboBox_layer then put text inside like Residential, Commercial and Industrial. What layers should I populate?

Comment: Hmm, my idea was that the `comboBox_layer` should contain all layers loaded into QGIS. Can you confirm this is what happens?

Comment: I created a comboBox and name it comboBox_layer.. Yes I back read and found out that  self.dlg.comboBox_layer.addItems(layer_list) should add my layers Naguilian.shp and naguiliandb.csv am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I suggest you open the **Python Console** when you run your plugin and see what errors (if any) show up when you click the `style_button`.

Comment: heres my python console result sir Joseph,

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/0b25641f97.jpg

Comment: I have created a simple dialog plugin for you, you can download it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/example_3), extract it to your `/.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory, restart QGIS and enable the plugin through the `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...` menu. I did not realise I needed to add a few more imports but it seems to work fine.

Comment: trying it now sir Joseph. :)

Comment: sir Joseph why the plugin icon is not loading in qgis?

Comment: Did you enable it from the menu: `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`? The plugin is called "Example".

Comment: its working now. :) really great help.. but could you explain to me the process? :)

Comment: Phew! Glad it works =). Process on how to create the plugin or show how the code works?

Comment: on how the code works so I can review it. :)

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - Edited post to include comments within the code ;)

Comment: A million thanks sir Joseph! :) Next time ill try with labels. :)